# grunt Warning Task "watch" not found

Tags: gruntjs

Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.initConfig({
 watch: {
  compass: {
    files: [
      'app/styles/**/*.{scss,sass}'
    ],
    tasks: 'compass reload'
  },
.....
grunt.registerTask('dev', 'watch');
```

when i run

```
grunt dev
```

i get the error

```
Warning: Task "watch" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

I use grunt-cli v0.1.6  and grunt v0.4.0, grunt-contrib-watch is installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well.

```
npm install grunt-contrib --save-dev
```

and add this line before the last line of grunt.js:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib');
```

Also, i had to have Ruby installed...

Comment: Wait, you had to install the entire grunt-contrib library?  That's a lot of dependencies.  How is this the best solution?

Comment: It is not the best solution may be. And sure, i do not use all of this features.

Answer (score 50):

You don't have to install the whole contrib-package. There is a separate one for watch

```
npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
```

and at the end:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
```

Comment: This is correct as the Grunt team doesn't recommend using `grunt-contrib` but rather each module individually.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if the plugin is not installed, you won't have an error launcinh `grunt watch`, just an error with impossibility to load the `watch` task.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but it was not properly answered yet since Serge stated

> grunt-contrib-watch is installed.

I would check if the whole Gruntfile is wrapped by

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

};
```

When you close this function (by accident) prematurely you get the described error.

Answer (score 0):

A browser update and a npm update worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

when I ran grunt watch on terminal, encountered error and fixed:

**Error**

```
grunt watch
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
```

**FIX in Terminal**

```
 brew install npm
 brew install node
```

- then you Test node and npm worked

  ```
  node -v
  npm -v
  ```
- Install Grunt

  ```
  npm install -g grunt-cli
  npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev
  ```
- Install Composer

  ```
  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
  ```
- then ran

  ```
  grunt watch
  ```

It worked!